# Pasting data in variable locations in VBA-Excel 

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from one Excel sheet to another, but the pasting destination needs to be a variable.

Essentially, what I want to do is open two excel sheets. On the first sheet, there will be some string, whose coordinates I save like this:

`sCurrentAddress = Selection.Address(True, True, xlA1, True)`

Based on the data already populating Sheet 2, an algorithm neatly finds the desired pasting location and saves these coordinates as follows:

`sDestinationAddress = Selection.Address(True, True, xlA1, True)`

Then what I'd like to do is paste the information from the first sheet into the second as follows:

`Selection.Copy (sDestinationAddress)`
but I receive error 1004: Runtime Error: Select method of range class failed.

Now, the first value I'm working on happens to be A4, and when I hover my mouse over "sDestinationAddress", it shows me that the value saved in sDestinationAddress is 
`'[exampleFile.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$A$4`

The macro fails unless I plug in the actual value like this:

`'Selection.Copy (Worksheets(1).Range("A4"))`

What do I need to do to use my sDestinationAddress as the argument for Selection.Copy?

---

(I'm sorry this lengthy and still inarticulate, yesterday was literally my first time looking at visual basic.)

About the algorithm:
I have 144 different headers to label the information in the 6 rows below. For example, I'm moving the data from a column headed: Inventory_S1_1 to a new spreadsheet. 'S1_1' on this one sheet implies for the other sheet: S=Diamond, 1 = Black, _1 = Player 1.   So my algorithm finds a header it hasn't dealt with yet (suppose here Inventory_S1_1 is the first header it hasn't dealt with), copies the column underneath the header, finds the location on the new spreadsheet corresponding to Player 1's Black Diamond, then pastes. The pasting algorithm works fine since the template was made by hand, but the searching algorithm gets lost looking for the headers, since it searches potentially jumbled data.

The problem is returning back to the sheet with the raw data on it.
Hovering my mouse over where I call set `sCurrentAddress = Selection` shows that `sCurrentAddress= Inventory_S1_2` once I've moved on to the second header, and then after I've pasted the `sDestinationAddress = 0`
And I'm fairly sure this is the exactly the problematic line:

`Set rCurrentRange = .Find(What:=sCurrentAddress, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)`
which I follow with

`Application.Goto rCurrentRange, True
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Offset(-1, 1).Select
Set sCurrentAddress = Selection`

It's with this line that I'm looking for the next header. When I was trying to use exact coordinates, this .Find seemed to work, but now it .Finds the first instance of 0 (sDestinationAddress), which was the first value in the copied material. Since it's always copying 0, then looking for the first 0, it never Finds the next header.

I realize that the Range Object has an .Address property, but I don't know if it would be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the ranges directly instead of using the Address

```
Dim rngSrc as Range, rngDest as range

Set rngSrc = Selection
'do your destination-finding thing
Set rngDest = Selection

rngSrc.Copy rngDest 'no need for parentheses here
```

**EDIT**

You rarely need to select ranges to work with them, and storing the actual range object in a variable is nearly always better than trying to work with range adresses.

If you need to keep the coordinates of a particular cell or range, then storing it in a range variable is the easiest approach.

One thing to keep in mind is that the default property of a range object is "Value"  - this would explain why you see a range's value when hovering your cursor over a range variable when stepping through code - it's the Value which is displayed.

If you're just copying cell values from one place to another then you don't even need to use `.Copy` if the two ranges are of the same dimensions:

```
rngDestination.Value = rngSource.Value
```

Comment: This does accomplish the task, but now I've lost "my place". The variable seems to be replaced with the value of the cell, and the coordinates are not present. I need to copy the next column over from Sheet1 and put that in a different place in Sheet2.  Maybe I can make a variable for the address, too.

Comment: Next column over is `rngSrc.Offset(0,1)`

Comment: how is that a problem? you are trying to copy the contents of one cell to another, no?

Comment: The variable stores the range object itself, not just the contents. Why do you think it just stores the contents?  It would help if you could update your question to describe how your algorithm decides what the destination range should be.  Is it just based on the column header?

Comment: I am trying to copy contents of once cell to the next, but I'm trying to keep the the coordinates of where the cell was. I apparently don't understand how to effectively use the fact that the entire range object is stored. I use `Application.Goto rCurrentRange, True`, and I feel like I almost want to invent ...`Goto rCurrentRange.xycoordinates` or something.